# Pandas: str.contains first word followed by colon

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand how to identify columns which start with a word, which is immediately followed by a colon.

I tried identifying that it should match less then 9 characters, followed by a colon - but with no lack.

The example is below:

1. Michael: this should be picked up pandas
2. This should not be picked up by pandas :(
3. This should not: be picked up by pandas either.

I have tried multiple ways with str.contains and str.match but can't seem to find a solution. Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str.match will accept a regular expression.  It seems like you want to match a sequence consisting of any number of consecutive letters, upper or lower case, followed immediately by a colon and then a space; and you don't care what comes afterwards.  In which case, try the code below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    ['Michael: this should be picked up pandas',
     'This should not be picked up by pandas :(',
     'This should not: be picked up by pandas either.'],
    columns=['TestColumn']
    )
df['StartsWithWord'] = df.TestColumn.str.match(r'[A-Za-z]+: .*')

print(df)
```

This results in the following output.

```
                                        TestColumn  StartsWithWord
0         Michael: this should be picked up pandas            True
1        This should not be picked up by pandas :(           False
2  This should not: be picked up by pandas either.           False
```

Answer (score 0):

the below function should do the job.

```
def check(s):
    s = s.split(":")
    if len(s) < 2:
        return False
    s = s[0].split(" ")
    if len(s) == 1:
        return True
    return False


df["identified_rows"] = df["some_column"].apply(check)
```

The idea being we split the text using the colon, if there is no colon in the split will return a list of length 1, this is less than 2 so it will return false.

Next we take the first element of the list and split it using a space, if the string does not contain a space the length of s will be one, and the function will return True, else the function returns False.

Comment: Thank you, Fred!